# JavaScript - How to use Map instead of For Loop

Tags: javascript

I want to use a map instead of for loop in this example.
I have a CSV Files that contains data

```
CSV file
address,type,building,geometry
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"
"This","is","an","example"

var geojsonFeature;

var globalData= data.map(function(d){return JSON.parse(d.geometry);});
var buildingData= data.map(function(d){return JSON.parse(d.type);});


for (i=0;i<globalData.legnth;i++)
{
geojsonFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": buildingData[i]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": globalData[i].coordinates
        }
    };

 listGeoData.push(geojsonFeature)

}
```

I wanted to replace the For-Loop with a map to get "listGeoData" this way.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes `listGeoData` was empty prior to the `for` loop.

```
var listGeoData = globalData.map(function(data,i) {
  return {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": buildingData[i]
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": data.coordinates
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: one suggestion: pass buildingData as a 2nd argument to map() and use "this" in the function instead of "buildingData". that allows code re-use and enables faster execution by avoiding the closure. it also makes it a "pure function" if you want something to brag about.

Comment: @dandavis Interesting idea. What if they want to include another array, such as `addressData[i]` in the json? That would be difficult unless they created a separate conglomerate object. Plus, this json is so specific I wouldn't worry too much about code re-use. I appreciate the discussion of weighing considerations against one another; in this case I think the scales tip to using `buildingData[i]`.

Comment: if you need a third argument, you have to use an impure function or pass an object/array to use as "this". given the option, i avoid hard-coding names into functions. i tend to put the functions outside the map() call so i can safely name them xbrowser for debugging purposes, and if needed later, it can be re-used without any refactoring.  That little bit of speed boost is reason enough, but as projects grow, it's easier to modify the logic to handle more situations than to re-implement the logic for each variation. i see no gain hard-coding that which needs not be.

Comment: @dandavis If the function did something generic like merging multiple arrays together in some way then I would agree with you. In this case, the entire json record is so application specific that code re-use is not an issue. Also by replacing `"name": buildingData[i]` with `"name": this[i]` makes it less obvious what the data actually is.

Comment: " In this case, the entire json record is so application specific that code re-use is not an issue" : how do you know what his CSV files are, how many he has, and what he's even doing to be able to make that call?

Comment: @dandavis OK I see your point there; yes perhaps this particular json record could potentially generalize to other CSV files that are being processed. My approach would be to keep it as is, which is more readable then using `this[i]` and generalize as the need comes about.

Comment: The size of the CSV file I have is : 800Mb. The both solutions (For-Loop & Map)are working, I am looking for an efficient one; what do you suggest ?

Comment: @user3001937 That's a hard question to answer without more information. What is your final output? This may properly be a separate question..

Comment: 800mb is a lot, i would do smaller chunks. if you have a map routine, you can easily break your big dataset up into many parts and crunch many segments at once, possibly on additional CPU cores, if you use Workers. you can do the same with for loops, but you'll have to re-work indexes each time you adjust the sub-load size. if your data has lots of repetition, you can cache the map function's results, which could slash ptime. without caching and working upon the whole set at once, i would suspect the for loop to be 10-20% faster, but test it yourself.